# Даже близко нет

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Логично ли употреблять фразу «даже близко нет» в значении «это не так». Почему «близко» уживается с категоричным «даже», если объект «близко» к истине? 
Логична ли фраза «даже близко нет», либо это искаженный вариант выражения «близко, но нет», употребляемого в значении: «это не совсем верно»? 
Правильно ли употреблять вместо «близко нет» фразу «это далеко не так».

Answer (score 1):

**Значение у этого сочетания следующее:** Здесь даже близко нет ничего похожего на истину. Это далеко не так.

Вот **примеры:**

Здесь даже близко нет ничего такого.

У нас нет столько денег, даже близко нет.

Даже близко нет, как раз всё наоборот.

Это даже близко не соответствует действительности.

Answer (score 0):

*Общий* смысл этого краткого выражения состоит в указании на *явное расхождение* высказывания (своего или собеседника) с действительностью, однако **буквально** оценивается ***не*** само высказывание (не то, насколько оно близко к реальному положению вещей, истине и т. п.), а принимается *обратный* порядок сопоставления: *насколько действительность далека* от приписываемого ей состояния - **даже близко** *в ней* **нет** ничего *похожего на сказанное* (ранее собеседником или приводимое самим говорящим).

Поэтому да, это выражение и по форме близко к "**это** далеко **не так**" (= действительность *совсем не такова*, как о ней сказано").